# How to upgrade mesa-opencl-icd

Tags: drivers, mesa, opencl

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 lts (amd64).
It seems that mesa 20.3 supports opencl 1.2, so
Register the kisak-mesa PPA repository and
I tried to install mesa 20.3.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: kisak / kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd
```

I did the above.

```
clinfo
Number of platforms 3
  Platform Name Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor The pocl project
  Platform Version OpenCL 1.2 pocl 1.4, None + Asserts, LLVM 9.0.1, RELOC, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG
  Platform Profile FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix POCL

  Platform Name AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3212.0)
  Platform Profile FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback
  Platform Extensions function suffix AMD

  Platform Name Clover
  Platform Vendor Mesa
  Platform Version OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.3.3 --kisak-mesa PPA
  Platform Profile FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix MESA
```

Displayed as above,
Platform Version OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.3.3 --kisak-mesa PPA
As you can see, the contents of Mesa's opencl-icd did not change.

Does anyone know how to change the contents of mesa-opencl-icd?

Comment: The answer given below is correct. The corresponding Mesa OpenCL implementation "clover" is not fully at 1.2 level. It looks that at least one merge request is missing, see Mesa MR !7357. However, it seems that newer Mesa builds can enforce at least some OpenCL 1.2 functionality via `CLOVER_DEVICE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.2 CLOVER_DEVICE_CLC_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.2`. But the future will be the new "rusticl" OpenCL Mesa implementation which supports **OpenCL 3.0**. And finally, it should be added that this works all perfectly well also with the **oibaf PPA** which brings a daily **Mesa devel** build.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [thread](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/1211540-opencl-1-2-support-merged-for-mesa-s-gallium3d-clover-while-opencl-3-0-is-being-tackled/page2), and they said the reason there:

> clover still only advertises OpenCL 1.1 as printf() is not supported
> yet.

environment variables modify can be override the problem:

```
CLOVER_PLATFORM_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.2 CLOVER_DEVICE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.2 CLOVER_DEVICE_CLC_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.2 clinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with mesa-opencl-icd not allowing upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.  Fix for me seemed to be to simply run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd
```

(I skipped the OP’s PPA line, and the PPA does not appear in my  sources.list .)